# Cannot read property '$cookies' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, cookies

I installed `vue-cookies` package, for my `vue` project.
but when I use `this.$cookies.set(...)`, i got  `Cannot read property '$cookies' of undefined` in console and It's not working.

---

main.js

```
//cookies
import VueCookies from "vue-cookies";
Vue.use(require("vue-cookies"));
Vue.use(VueCookies);
```

Should I add more code?

Comment: The error says "this" is undefined. Where did you use this.$cookies.set(...)?

Comment: oh, tnx, i should use `this.cookies.set(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution
> I should use `this.cookies.set(...)` and there is no need to `$`.